# Use existing HTML 5 themes with Angular 4+

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I bought a theme from theme Forest and want to use it with angular 4, the theme has a lot of scripts and once i integrated it with angular cli every thing broke, i kept the css file references in the html head tag and js references at the end of the body tag and it worked fine but some of the js functionality didn't work specially jquery stuff, how can i solve this.

Comment: This might take some time. Themes usually come with a lot of dependencies. Have you had a look at the [angular cli's guide to installing 3rd party packages](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is **framework**, which means that

1. It gives you certain rules
2. It gives you project structure
3. You have to abide by the rules to make it work in Angular way

Solution
 4. Take the pages, break them to  component
 6. Add css on component level
 7. Avoid using Jquery or Js to manipulate DOM, do it the angular way